Can the closed-form solution for ridge regression be used in training neural networks?
Is it established that the closed-form solution of ridge regression can be used during the training of neural networks? If so:

What are the potential benefits of using it?

In what scenarios would this approach be particularly useful?


I want to understand whether this technique has practical applications in neural network training or if it is mainly of theoretical interest.

What kind of usage are you thinking of?

Ridge regression has a closed-form solution for a linear model. Once you have a nonlinear activation function, however, the existence of a closed-form solution is not guaranteed by the logic that guarantees one in the linear case.

@gunes I was thinking of Layer-wise Training, randomly initialize the weights of the first hidden layer, treat the activations of this layer as the "input" to the next layer and use ridge regression to train the weights of the second hidden layer, repeat this process for subsequent layers. Maybe Kernel ridge regression might be more effective.
